# React: function as useState's initial value - which way is correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

What is the correct way to pass an function as a initial value:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(calculateInitialValue); //1.
const [count, setCount] = useState(() => calculateInitialValue); //2.
```

I already know this one is not correct, because it will call the calculateInitialValue function on every state change:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(calculateInitialValue()); //3.
```

But the first two variants seem to me to have an identical effect, the function is called only on first render. What is the difference between them? Can both be used or not? What is the best practice and why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "What is the correct way to pass an function" - both of them aren't doing this. So there is no comparison

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I mean what is the difference, why wrapping the function name into an anonymous function if just the function name would do the same (as it seems to me)? In a video, tutor said "wrap the function into an anonymous function to prevent unnecessary calls", but did not explain why nor suggest more options. He only said the 3rd option was wrong, but I found out the 1st option does the same as the second. The calculateInitialValue function just returns a random number from which a count starts.

Answer (score 2):

The two declarations are the same, but the first one will simplify your code.
But you need change the second declaration to call your inner function `calculateInitialValue`:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(() => calculateInitialValue()); //2.
```

Comment: Wouldn't option 2 set `count == calculateInitialValue` instead of executing it?

Comment: @samthecodingman the function will not be executed until we call it like this count().

Comment: That was my point, was just correcting OP's syntax error and your original incorrect statement.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the initial state is, if it is just a number or simple value, you can pass the first way.

If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

Read more about `lazy initial state` and the `useState` hook in React [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state).